# How can I unit test a method that spins off a Task.ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, synchronizationcontext

Consider the following code:

```
public interface IBar
{
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetStringsAsync();
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IBar bar, IList<string> initial)
    {
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        if (initial == null || !initial.Any())
            AddContent(bar);
        else
            MyCollection.AddRange(initial);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get; private set; }

    public void AddContent(IBar bar)
    {
        var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
        bar.GetStringsAsync().ContinueWith(
            task => MyCollection.AddRange(task.Result),
            cancel,
            TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCancel,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

How can I unit test the Foo.AddContent method? I'd like to test that the strings my mock IBar provides do, in fact, get added to the collection, but the asserts always get called before the task has updated the collection.

I'm using .NET 4.5.2. My first choice would have been to use `async` and `await` in AddContent, but because the method is used in the constructor I thought it would be best to avoid that. I need something that can initiate the asynchronous loading of data but that will not wait for it to finish.

Recommendations on how to rewrite AddContent are welcome, but I've already tried a lot of things and this is the only one that has worked well, so what I'd really like is a way to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

Use Stephen Cleary's Asynchronous Initialization pattern found here.

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

**Update**

Since the question has changed, the requirement is now to have the constructor take on the variable `IBar`.  I would suggest the following based on the hard requirement of the `IBar` variable being passed into the constructor:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        MyCollection.AddRange(bar.GetStringsAsync().Result));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get; private set; }

    public async Task AddContent(IBar bar)
    {
        MyCollection.AddRange(await bar.GetStringsAsync());
    }
}
```

NOTE: the `public` method still utilizes the preferred mechanism `async / await`, but the constructor simply calls `.Result`.  This is a *blocking call* in the constructor and a very poor practice.  This could easily be argued to be something that you should never, ever do...

I highly suggest that your constructor takes the initial strings instead as such, (especially considering that it is only being used for the strings that it returns!):

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        MyCollection.AddRange(strings);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get; private set; }

    public async Task AddContent(IBar bar)
    {
        MyCollection.AddRange(await bar.GetStringsAsync());
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test()
{
    IBar bar = GetMockedBarImpl();
    var sut = new Foo(await bar.GetStringsAsync());        

    Assert.IsTrue(sut.MyCollection.Any());
    // TODO: Add asserts for known strings in collection...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be roughly equivalent to `var strings = await bar.GetStringsAsync(); cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); MyCollection.AddRange(strings);`?

Comment: I think that was a step to far - you just removed the cancellation logic

Comment: It wasn't being utilized anyways.

Comment: I've updated my question. I would have preferred to use `async`/`await`, but the method needs to be callable from the constructor.

Comment: I *really* don't want to block in my constructor, but I need to be able to call AddContent from the constructor, hence the current version of AddContent.

Comment: You might find what you're looking for here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html.  This is Stephen Cleary's article on asynchronous code from the constructor.  I still do not understand why you **need** to do this, to me it should be avoided.

Comment: David, Stephen Cleary's Asynchronous Initialization pattern in the article you linked was exactly what I was looking for. If you could add that to your answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score -1):

looks like there is an inherit race condition with the code in question. I would wait for `GetStringAsync` to complete and assign to `MyCollection`.

```
public void AddContent(IBar bar)
{
    var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var result = bar.GetStringsAsync().ContinueWith(
        task => task.Result,
        cancel,
        TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCancel,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

   MyCollection.AddRange(result.Result);
}
```

or simply

```
public void AddContent(IBar bar)
{
    var result = bar.GetStringsAsync().Result;
    MyCollection.AddRange(result);
}
```